# Sending larger JSON strings via HTTP using Node

Tags: json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am working on sending JSON data from my HTTP server to my client.  I have been successful in sending smaller sized JSON responses to the client,  but once I have to wait and collect all the data before sending,  my code does not function properly.  I am using the .on('data', function (){}) method to collect the data and build it back up and the .on('end', function(){}) to try sending the data,  but my code never enters either of these methods.

My code for sending the larger sized JSON data is below:

```
  exports.sendJson = function (req, resp, data) {

    resp.writeHead(200, "Valid EndPoints", { "Content-Type": "application/json" });

    var payload = '';

    resp.on('data', function(data){
          payload += data;
      })
      .on('end', function(){
        resp.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
      });
    resp.end();
  };
```

My code that works fine for smaller sized JSON data is as follows:

```
 exports.sendJson = function (req, resp, data) {
     resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });

     if(data) {
      resp.write(JSON.stringify(data));
     }

      resp.end();
  };
```

Thanks in advance.  I'm actually pretty happy I got this far.

Comment: Could you show the emitter of the `data` event?

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP server response is a [`Writable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams); it does not emit `data` events.

If the thing you pass in to `sendJson`'s `data` parameter is an object, you just do exactly what you're doing in the second example.  There is no need to buffer anything.  (If the thing you pass to `sendJson` is a stream, just `pipe` it to the response.)

(When parsing received JSON, you *must* buffer the data you get from a [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) -- the HTTP response on the client.)